# How to assign this variable manually

Tags: python, mysql, list, types

Python 3 this snippet:

```
var.execute(query)
for x in var:
    print(x)
print(type(var))
```

Output on console:

```
(1, 'sarah', None, '', 0, datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 25, 16, 16, 2), 'administrator')
<class 'mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor'>
```

var was generated by execute an mysql query, not by manual assingment.
Question:
What is the syntax equivalent if var were assign manually, like var = (????) in replace of var.execute(query) ?

I want to do data manipulation on var, is var a list?
What are the methods to manipulate var?

Comment: `var` is a cursor, which is iterable and will produce a sequence of tuples. You can emulate the same effect with any other iterable of tuples, like a list of tuples.

Comment: Note you can only iterate over `var` _once per query_. If you want to do so repeatedly, do `my_new_var = var.fetchall()` to get a `list`.

Comment: You can emulate this more closely by creating an **iterator over a sequence**, rather than a sequence itself. For example. `var = iter([(1, 'sarah', None, '', datetime(2022, 12, 25, 16, 16, 2), 'administrator')])` That will reproduce the behaviour you're seeing where you can't iterate more than once over `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable *var* is an iterable comprised of zero or many tuples.

You could emulate this by constructing a list as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime

var = [
    (1, 'sarah', None, '', datetime(2022, 12, 25, 16, 16, 2), 'administrator')
]

for x in var:
    print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
(1, 'sarah', None, '', datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 25, 16, 16, 2), 'administrator')
```

Comment: Thanks. thats  clear some parts, another still unclear from my original code, if I repeat the for loop and print:
```
var.execute(query)
for x in var:
    print(x)
for x in var:
    print(x)
```
The Output only 1 line (should be 2 equivalent lines):
```
(1, 'sarah', None, '', datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 25, 16, 16, 2), 'administrator')

```
It's like var not stored, so I still unable to do data method on var.
assign : a = var also not helped.
Any way to make var persistently stored?

Comment: Nevermind, I can do copy the var to other list variable, using for loop and append inside the loop. And I can work on that new variable.